# Did NASA tell the Skylab astronauts to "Stop running around!"?

Tags: nasa, attitude-determination-and-control, reduced-gravity-sports, skylab

[This answer](https://space.stackexchange.com/a/701/12102) to the question starts with:

> [This video](http://youtu.be/S_p7LiyOUx0?t=26s) may help to answer your question. Starting at about 00:24, you can see an astronaut running around the "exercise wheel" of Skylab (an early NASA space station program, which followed the Apollo moon landings). Basically after some time, NASA told the astronauts to stop running around like this because it was causing more propellants to be used to maintain Skylab's correct attitude (orientation) in space (**at least this is what I've been told...it would be nice to find a reference to back this claim up**).

Are there any references to back this up? Did NASA tell the Skylab astronauts to "Stop running around!" due to excessive use of thruster propellant?

---

Gotta love the vintage music track, one of the zillion instances of the [Amen Break](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Amen_break) (original heard after `01:26` in [The Winstons - Amen Brother](https://youtu.be/GxZuq57_bYM?t=86)).

Comment: there isn't an `exercise` tag, so I've made due.

Comment: http://ablogaboutnothinginparticular.com/?p=1042   https://history.nasa.gov/SP-401/ch13.htm

Comment: @MBM I've linked to that in [Do space stations have standardized officer designations for crew?](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/34753/12102)

Comment: Wasn't Skylab's orientation controlled by gyros rather than thrusters?

Comment: @DaveGremlin If they always ran in the same direction, then...

Comment: @DaveGremlin [How many times would two astronauts have to run around Skylab to turn it by 10 arc minutes?](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/35960/12102)

Comment: Why would they need to use RCS propellant to null out the astronaut-induced perturbations?  Just have them run the other way for a while...

Comment: @Sean That's a good point! You can consider asking that at the [source of the quote](https://space.stackexchange.com/a/701/12102) or even post it as a new question.

Comment: @uhoh: [Now asked at the source of the quote!](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/690/how-does-astronaut-activity-from-within-affect-a-spacecraft/701#comment117616_701)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I think [they did](http://hdl.handle.net/2060/19740021165) (page 120):

[image]

The reference is a bit indirect, but the [water storage](https://archive.org/details/MSFC-0101590) was right next to the 'exercise ring' (storage lockers):

[image]

Comment: Interesting, yes this does sound like the right kind of thing.