# Why did Skylab have a thick blue flexible cord running down its central axis?

Tags: space-station, identify-this-object, skylab

After watching the video below (found [here](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/34570/12102) and [here](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/34569/12102) and [here](https://space.stackexchange.com/a/701/12102)) I am reminded of the series of possibly less than 100% serious questions here about being weightless in the middle of a large volume and considering the options for reaction masses to get to the side and grab hold of something.

In the video I noticed that there is a central cord or rope to hold on to, possibly for this very reason, or possibly it had a different function as well. What was this for?

---

Gotta love the vintage music track, one of the zillion instances of the [Amen Break](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Amen_break) (original heard after `01:26` in [The Winstons - Amen Brother](https://youtu.be/GxZuq57_bYM?t=86)).

Comment: I never realized Skylab was so big...!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It appears to have actually been a pole, not a cord.

> Handrails and handholds, colored blue for quick identification, were
>   located throughout Skylab. A removable, collapsible "fireman's pole"
>   extending from the workshop hatch to the floor of the forward
>   compartment provided a means of rapid movement. However, the
>   astronauts soon found that they could move about easily without using
>   it, and it was removed and stowed.

[Source](https://history.nasa.gov/SP-400/ch5.htm)

[image]

[Picture source](http://spacearchitect.org/pubs/NASA-JSC-09545.pdf)

Cue the pole-dancing jokes: 3, 2, 1 ....

Comment: Speaking of "colored blue, for quick identification": [Can there be color blind astronauts?](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/35937/12102)