# How many times would two astronauts have to run around Skylab to turn it by 10 arc minutes?

Tags: attitude, attitude-determination-and-control, reduced-gravity-sports, skylab

[This answer](https://space.stackexchange.com/a/701/12102) to the question starts with:

> [This video](http://youtu.be/S_p7LiyOUx0?t=26s) may help to answer your question. Starting at about 00:24, you can see an astronaut running around the "exercise wheel" of Skylab (an early NASA space station program, which followed the Apollo moon landings). Basically after some time, NASA told the astronauts to stop running around like this because it was causing more propellants to be used to maintain Skylab's correct attitude (orientation) in space (**at least this is what I've been told...it would be nice to find a reference to back this claim up**).

From [this answer](https://space.stackexchange.com/a/35951/12102) which shows the following screen shot from page 120 in this **large, 436 page PDF** of NASA Technical Memorandum [NASA TM-X 64817: MSFC Skylab Attitude and Pointing Control System Mission Evaluation](https://ntrs.nasa.gov/archive/nasa/casi.ntrs.nasa.gov/19740021165.pdf):

> [image]

**Question:** How many times would two astronauts have to run around on this track to turn Skylab by 10 arc minutes around its long axis?

The question is a bit challenging and may be difficult to answer, depending on the orientation of the long axis with respect to the orbital plane and direction of motion. If necessary to simplify answering, one can choose it to be perpendicular to the orbital plane.

[image: Classic NASA Film - Skylab - #4, jogging]

Source: [Classic NASA Film - Skylab - #4](https://youtu.be/S_p7LiyOUx0)

Clarifications that were captured in comments which have since been moved:

- This question is about rotation, it’s not about the oscillation. Rotation around the long axis by 10 arc minutes changes the direction of the other two axes by that amount.
- When the astronauts stop “rotating” the spacecraft will also stop rotating, but it will have been rotated by a small amount.
- Assume that the two astronauts want to do this on purpose and have disabled or adjusted the attitude control system so as not to fight or resist this rotation.
- Assume that the astronauts are running in the same direction spaced by 180 degrees, opposite each other.
- If it takes a long time, there may be some complexities depending on if Skylab is currently operating in an Earth-oriented or Sun-oriented attitude (for more see the linked NASA Technical Memorandum). You may make some simplifying assumptions if it helps.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/93391/discussion-on-question-by-uhoh-how-many-times-would-two-astronauts-have-to-run-a).

Comment: key clarifications in those comments have been added back into the question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To create the oscillation around the Z axis, they'd have to run around once.

The oscillation in the X axis would be created with each footfall.

Skylab was about 1000 times as massive as an astronaut. Estimating the astronauts centre of mass to be at about three quarters of the circumferance, and the distribution of Skylab's mass to be skewed to around seven eigths from the centre, then:

The acceleration to set two astronaut rotating is three halves, by eight over seven thousands, so the astronaut would have to go around $\frac{1750}{3}$ times for each rotation of Skylab we only want Skylab to go around a sixth of a degree, so the astronaut would go around $\frac{1750}{3(6\times360)}$ times in the time Skylab took to rotate 10 arc-minutes - or about a quarter time around.

oops, it's r-squared, not r. So that makes it five eighths of a circuit.

Comment: Okay but I've asked about a rotation, not an oscillation.

Comment: "**Question:** How many times would two astronauts have to run around on this track to turn Skylab by 10 arc minutes around its long axis?" I'm asking exactly this question. The oscillations are interesting and I encourage you or anyone else to ask a new question about it.

Comment: @uhoh In my interpretation, your question title is about *orientation*, which is not oscillation and also not rotation. :-)

Comment: @peterh orientations are usually described as a sequence of rotations.

Comment: The use of “oscillation” is infelicitous, but the calculation (within its approximations) is right. Running then stopping will cause Skylab to rotate the other way then stop after some angular displacement.

Comment: @BobJacobsen [confirmed](https://space.stackexchange.com/a/36022/12102)!

Answer (score 1):

**tl;dr:** I get good agreement with [@JCRM's estimate](https://space.stackexchange.com/a/35961/12102)!

---

Moments of inertia found in NASA [TM X-64746 Skylab Attitude Control and Angular Momentum Desaturation with One Double-Gimbaled Control Moment Gyro](https://ntrs.nasa.gov/archive/nasa/casi.ntrs.nasa.gov/19730015124.pdf) also found [archived here](https://archive.org/details/NASA_NTRS_Archive_19730015124/page/n9):

```
                                   Command/Service Module
                                      undocked  docked
Minimum Moment-of-Inertia       Ix     0.893     0.992      x 10^6 kg m^2
Intermediate Moment-of-Inertia Iy      3.813     6.168      x 10^6 kg m^2
Maximum Moment-of-Inertia      Iz      3.882     6.245      x 10^6 kg m^2
```

I assume that it is Ix that corresponds to rotation about the "long axis".

Starting with a diameter of 6.6 meters, I estimate the track radius to be 2.8 meters and the pair of astronauts' *effective* centers of mass to be 0.9 meters higher at 1.9 meters. To do it right you'd have to integrate $r^2 \frac{dm(r)}{dr} dr$.

I get the moment of inertia for a pair of 65 kg astronauts to be 470 kg m^2, which is about **2,110 times smaller** than the moment of inertia of the ISS around the x or long axis.

**note:** Thanks to @JCRM [for noting](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/35960/how-many-times-would-two-astronauts-have-to-run-around-skylab-to-turn-it-by-10-a/36022?noredirect=1#comment114415_36022) that it's necessary to use the moments of inertia when the Command/Service module is docked. That's how the astronauts got there in the first place!

10 arc minutes is **2,160 times smaller** than a complete circle.

So to rotate Skylab by 10 arc minutes, the two astronauts would have to "jog" only 0.98 of one lap.

[image: Skylab's moments of inertia]

[image: Skylab's moments of inertia]

Comment: X was the cylindrical axis

Comment: @JCRM thanks for that, I've made an edit. Yes it certainly makes sense; if somebody is home there'll be a "car in the driveway".

Comment: Compared to the 470 kg m^2 from the orbital motion of two astronauts, the extra moment from their rotation is very small. For experimental results, see [MOMENTS OF INERTIA AND CENTERS OF GRAVITY OF THE LIVING HUMAN BODY, DTIC AD0410451, 1963](https://apps.dtic.mil/docs/citations/AD0410451).  (The pictures paint an interesting story of the life of early-60's Air Force personnel) See page 22; standing y axis is listed as only 103 lb.in^2 which seems quite small to me.

Comment: @BobJacobsen moment of inertia must be defined relative to some specific center of rotation. In the answer above, I've calculated the moment of inertia *of a pair of astronauts rotating about Skylab's central axis* whereas in your reference I'm guessing it's the moment of inertia of a single human about their own center of mass. Apples and oranges.

Comment: To do it accurately, you need both. The astronauts total L comes from an orbital term (the running) plus rotating one turn per lap: like the moon, they keep one point toward the center of their overall motion. That second term then replaces the need to integrate you mention in your answer.

Comment: @BobJacobsen to do it accurately, you simply integrate $r^2 \frac{dm(r)}{dr} dr$ as I mentioned in the answer. In my back-of-the-envelope calculation I've collapsed the astronauts mass distributions $m(r)$ into two lumps located 0.9 meters above their feet. The astronauts together form a single rigid rotating object. They could be two balls on a stick, or a single ring, or a pair of sticks, or one long stick. The only thing that survives the integral is the moment of inertia about the center of mass.

Comment: Agree that’s an approximation. Disagree that integrating over the shape of a human is “simply”. Instead, use parallel axis theorem to separate result into the motion of c.m., which you have, plus a term for motion _around_ c.m. Which has been experimentally measured, see paper.  Example: to find moment of Moon, you could do that integration, or find moments of orbital plus rotational motion (which are locked to same rate) and add.

Comment: @BobJacobsen why don't you post an answer and show what you mean using equations, demonstrating why what I've said is not correct? You may have an alternate method to approximate, but I'm not convinced that it's better. Discussion in words alone can go on for a long time without being particularly productive, but if you show me, then I and others can learn something new!

Comment: Bob's source does act as a source for an average weight of Mercury era American airmen being 75 kg

Comment: “the extra moment from their rotation is very small”; I can leave it at that, as I agree your answer is right within approximations. The rest is just how to show that.

Comment: it also gives their center of mass as 0.98 m above the floor when standing (well, 31 inches down a 69.4 inch body),

Comment: @BobJacobsen now I won't be able to sleep until I can get to the bottom of this ;-) Ah, I think what you are talking about will indeed agree with the integral, and it is my collapsing the astronauts to points that "looses" some of the moment that can be recovered by considering the moments of each astronaut about their centers plus the moment of the centers around the axis. I think I've got it now.